# maxima multiple trigonometric equations

Tags: matlab, octave, trigonometry, maxima, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve an equation using **maxima 13.04.2** but the answer isn't what I expect.
Example:

```
y2=A2*cos(2*pi*f2*t+phase2)  we know A2=.4,f2=6.4951,t=1, trying to find **phase2** 
y2=.4*cos(2*pi*6.4951+phase2)
```

I tried to solve the **y2 equation for phase2** in maxima but it got rid of the cos function

```
kill(all);
A:A; phase:phase; solve(A*cos(2*pi*f*t+phase)=0,phase);
```

The answer that came back was

[image: strange answer]

I thought something like this was suppose to come back

```
y2 = A2×cos(2πf2t + φ2) ⇒

y2/A2 = cos(2πf2t + φ2) ⇒

arccos(y2/A2) = 2πf2t + φ2 ⇒

arccos(y2/A2) - 2πf2t = φ2
```

so I could then plug in the vales
**A2 = 0.4, f2 = 6.4951, t = 1 and get the phase**

Any ideas how to get maxima to get the correct format?
PS: Yes I know I can do it by hand but I have thousands of equations like this and I plan on using octave arrays to call maxima to solve them and bring the answers back into octave.

Comment: Hi Rick, it's me again. :-) I think you forgot to specify the frequency in your harmonic factor: instead of `2*pi*t` please write `2*pi*f*t`. Also, the equation should be `=y` not `=0`, so you get the phase for all the possible values of `y` (btw, the software found the right solution for `f=1` and `y=0`).

Comment: Btw, I can't se why this is tagged with "Octave". If you want a symbolic solver for Octave I suggest octsympy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems straightforward.

```
(%i1) e:A*cos(2*%pi*f*t + phi) = y;
(%o1)                     cos(2 %pi f t + phi) A = y
(%i2) solve (e, phi);
solve: using arc-trig functions to get a solution.
Some solutions will be lost.
                                      y
(%o2)                     [phi = acos(-) - 2 %pi f t]
                                      A
(%i3) subst ([A = 0.4, f = 6.4951, t = 1], %o2);
(%o3)                  [phi = acos(2.5 y) - 12.9902 %pi]
```

Couple of notes. (1) `solve` can solve this equation, which is good, but bear in mind that it is fairly limited in its capability, and you can probably make up other equations that it can't solve. There are some other options for solving equations in Maxima, but it general that is a weak area. (2) Maybe instead of switching back and forth between Maxima and Octave, you can just code equation `%o2` in Octave and evaluate that for different values of the parameters.