# Is there a way to solve trigonometric equations in WXMAXIMA ,like Lagrange equation of motion?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, maxima, wxmaxima

[image: WXMAXIMA CODE IMAGE]

Is there a way to solve trigonometric equations in WXMAXIMA ,like Lagrange equation of motion?

Comment: [wxmaxima](https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima) does not appear to have an API. I'm guessing this is not a programming question. Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: @jww I think Maxima is a programming language (in the same way that Mathematica is). This question has multiple issues (code as images rather than text, probably too broad/unclear) but I think it probably is on-topic. Although possibly one of the Math-based Stack Exchange sites might be better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maxima multiple trigonometric equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508179/maxima-multiple-trigonometric-equations)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions .If you know some sites where experts can help me to find the solution .

Comment: I think your best bet is to post a message to the maxima-discuss mailing list describing the problem and your efforts to solve it. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: if you post a picture of your code instead of your code as text there is a good chance that nobody will try to reproduce your problem because nobody is willing to typewrite your code from the picture instead of copying and pasting it.